# How to get child datagrid values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, parent-child

How can I save values in child popup `DataGridView`?

I am having parent datagridview and child `DataGridView` in vb.net

Consider I have 2 columns and 2 rows.

When I click 1st column, I will get child `DataGridView` just near to this cell. Child `DataGridView` also has 2 rows and 2 columns where I can enter values.

When I click 2nd column, I'll get another new child `DataGridView` near this cell.

Now if I move back to first column, values I entered are lost. How can I save entered values in popup child window?

Here is my code:

```
sub cell_click Dim _pointCell As Point = Me.DgV.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, True).Location Dim _pointGrid As Point = DgV.Location Dim _pointLocation As Point _pointLocation.X = _pointCell.X 'width _pointLocation.Y = _pointCell.Y 'height SelectionInGrid() mPopup.Show(DgV.PointToScreen(New Point(_pointLocation.X, _pointLocation.Y))) end sub

Public SelectionInGrid() Dim t1,t2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() Dim gv As New DataGridView

    gv.Columns.Add(t1)
    gv.Columns.Add(t2)
    gv.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Employee"
    gv.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Currency"

    gv.Width = t1.Width + t2.Width

    Dim mControlHost As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(gv)
    mControlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty
    mControlHost.AutoSize = False

    mPopup = New ToolStripDropDown()
    mPopup.Padding = Padding.Empty
    mPopup.Items.Add(mControlHost)
End
```

---

```
sub cell_click
            Dim _pointCell As Point = Me.DgV.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, True).Location
            Dim _pointGrid As Point = DgV.Location
            Dim _pointLocation As Point
           _pointLocation.X = _pointCell.X 'width
           _pointLocation.Y = _pointCell.Y  'height
            SelectionInGrid()
            mPopup.Show(DgV.PointToScreen(New Point(_pointLocation.X, _pointLocation.Y)))
end sub

Public SelectionInGrid()
    Dim t1,t2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Dim gv As New DataGridView

    gv.Columns.Add(t1)
    gv.Columns.Add(t2)
    gv.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Employee"
    gv.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Currency"

    gv.Width = t1.Width + t2.Width

    Dim mControlHost As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(gv)
    mControlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty
    mControlHost.AutoSize = False

    mPopup = New ToolStripDropDown()
    mPopup.Padding = Padding.Empty
    mPopup.Items.Add(mControlHost)
End
```

Comment: We need to see your code to be able to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @WozzeC :  Can u check out the added code??

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the SelectionInGrid Sub which is called every single time you click a cell. In this function you have these lines:

```
Dim gv As New DataGridView
Dim mControlHost As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(gv)
mPopup = New ToolStripDropDown()
```

This means that everytime cell_click runs a new DataGridView, a new ToolStripControlHost and a new ToolStripDropDown are created. To solve this you need to keep track of the different ToolStripDropDowns. For example using a dictionary:

```
Private PopUps As New Dictionary(Of String, ToolStripDropDown)    
sub cell_click
Dim _pointCell As Point = Me.DgV.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, True).Location
Dim _pointGrid As Point = DgV.Location
Dim _pointLocation As Point
_pointLocation.X = _pointCell.X 'width
_pointLocation.Y = _pointCell.Y  'height     
If PopUps.ContainsKey(<Parent Selected cell identifyer>) Then
   mPopup = PopUps(<Parent Selected cell identifyer>)
Else
    SelectionInGrid()
    PopUps.Add(<Parent Selected cell identifyer>,mPopup)
End If
mPopup.Show(DgV.PointToScreen(New Point(_pointLocation.X, _pointLocation.Y)))
end sub
```

I do believe this should work. "Parent Selected cell identifyer" must be something unique from the Parent DGV row/cell that was clicked.